# Spark table transformation (ERROR: 5063)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have the following data:

```
val RDDApp = sc.parallelize(List("A", "B", "C"))
val RDDUser = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3))
val RDDInstalled =  sc.parallelize(List((1, "A"), (1, "B"), (2, "B"), (2,  "C"), (3, "A"))).groupByKey
val RDDCart = RDDUser.cartesian(RDDApp)
```

I want to map this data so that I have an RDD of tuples with (userId, Boolean if the letter is given for user). I thought I found a solution with this:

```
val results = RDDCart.map (entry =>
   (entry._1, RDDInstalled.lookup(entry._1).contains(entry._2))
)
```

If I call `results.first`, I get `org.apache.spark.SparkException: SPARK-5063`. I see the problem with the Action within the Mapping function but do not know how I can work around it so that I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `join` and `mapValues`:

```
RDDCart.join(RDDInstalled).mapValues{case (x, xs) => xs.toSeq.contains(x)}
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way to do it if the dataset is very large?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand all the logic. In particular Cartesian required to create `RDDCart` smells fishy. But join by itself is probably the only efficient __exact__ solution you can get here if neither  dataset fits into memory.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I kind of guessed that this is the best logic to create the result, but if there are other solutions to this - solution which do not use the Cartesian function - I would be very happy to find out about them. It's not that the datasets are too big but doing a `join` on both datasets takes ages.

Comment: You know, technically speaking `RDDInstalled` completely defines sparse matrix of user-app relationships. This is why I don't see the point in anything else. If `RDDInstalled` is small enough to be handled locally (lets say  less than a few GBs or so depending on your configuration) you can collect and broadcast. Another option is to create bloom filter on it and pass it to map.